# creating and adjusting color of L.polygon in leafletjs

Tags: geolocation, leaflet

I am working with the leaflet library v. 0.7.7  I want to create a polygon, set the markers and define the polygon colors, but there is no way

```
  var polygon = new L.polygon();
    <c:forEach var="marker" items="${markers}" varStatus="rowIndex">
    var marker${rowIndex.index} = L.marker([${marker.lat},${marker.lng}],{icon: yellowIcon,title: '${marker.title}'}).addTo(mymap)
            .bindPopup( "${marker.HTMLMarkerPopupCode}").openPopup();        
    polygon.addLayer        (marker${rowIndex.index});    
 </c:forEach>

    polygon.setStyle({fillColor: '#0000FF'});
    polygon.setStyle({color: 'red'});
    polygon.setStyle({fillOpacity: 0.5});
    mymap.addLayer( polygon );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately an [`L.polygon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon) is a single layer, not a Layer Group. It is not supposed to contain other layers / markers.

The `polygon.addLayer()` line should throw an error.

If my understanding is correct, you would like to draw a polygon which vertices are markers? In that case, you should read your markers coordinates and store them into an array, then build your polygon using that array of coordinates.

Then the styling / colors should work.